# Is there a translation to English of Serre's GAGA?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, translation, gaga

I am trying to find an English translation of J.-P. Serre, *[Géométrie algébrique et géométrie analytique](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1956__6__1_0/)* (GAGA). However, I am unable to find a translation searching for it in google. Does anybody know about any existing translation?

Comment: Try this: https://achinger.impan.pl/fac/fac.pdf

Comment: @Satan'sMinion Yeah, I was aware of that translation of FAC, thank you anyway ^^. But the translators don't seem to have translated GAGA as well.

Comment: Fair enough. If you're seriously interested in this kind of math, you will need to learn enough French to read these papers anyway. ;)

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you are looking for, but you only need to learn a small number of words in French and a sprinkling of grammar to read Serre's papers, his writing style is quite simple.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, on the internet archive I've found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180728222951/http://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Earnoldt/Serre-GAGA.dvi) (the file is .dvi, I converted it to pdf [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tr3kwnq4msj6lvx/J.-P.%20Serre%2C%20Algebraic%20Geometry%20and%20Analytic%20Geometry.pdf?dl=0)). This translation was uploaded to the no longer existing personal webpage of Trevor Arnold at the McMaster University (his webpage is [held](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114151828/http://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Earnoldt/) on the internet archive). But not the file nor Arnold's webpage say who translated it. If anyone has any info about the translator identity, that would be nice to know :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.  Would you be willing to post it someplace that doesn't require setting up an account?